# why the Asm83CEPgrm command is not available on mi TI-83 premium CE

Tags: assembly, texas-instruments

I was hoping to make an assembly program on my TI-83 Premium CE calculator but the Asm83CEPgrm command  wasn't available so i don't know what to do...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm running version 5.3.1.0058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CE OS 5.3.1 disables that command, whether or not the calc is in exam mode, because apparently some teachers want to do some exams in class but not enable exam mode, and writing an Asm program could be used to cheat...
But anyway, a solution (among others) is just to transfer a program with TI-Connect CE, that contains this token. Then you're free to use it (TI themselves document this workaround).

Note that with `Asm83CEPrgm` you can only write assembly programs in Hex directly, so unless you know all the opcodes on top of your head... it probably won't be that useful. If you want to do some native development, Assembly or C, it'll have to be done on the computer anyway...

Comment: what IDE do you recommend to write code for the calculator ?

Comment: Or maybe a compiler/SDK ?

Comment: Among other things, TI Connect CE, which has a builtin TI-Basic program editor. For C/Asm, take a look at the community SDK: https://github.com/CE-Programming/toolchain which you can use with any IDE you want (then just run make, basically).
An online IDE with the sdk/toolchain ready to use is also available here, for C and ASM dev: https://tiplanet.org/pb/ (disclaimer, I'm the author of TI-Planet's Project Builder)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! ^^